# Replace strings in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, replace, command

I have a file named index.hbs and I want to replace

```
   {{#if description}}
      <div class="kss-description">
        {{{description}}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}
```

`{{{description}}}` with `{{{splitTitle description}}}`

I am using this command

```
(Get-Content $IndexHbsFilePath -Raw) -replace '<div class="kss-description">{{{description}}}</div>' , '<div class="kss-description">{{{sss description}}}</div>' | Set-Content $IndexHbsFilePath
```

But its not updating the file.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: You need to match any whitespace before and after the placeholder token in your regular expression: `\s*{{{description}}}\s*`

Comment: On top of what [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708727/replace-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell#comment125001022_70708727) commented, `-replace` uses regex and therefore you need to use `[regex]::Escape()` on the string that is to be replaced. In this case, all opening brackets need a `\` in front.

Comment: I recommend you to use a html parser like [HTMLDocument2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mshtml.ihtmldocument2.write) to replace your placeholders.

Comment: Thanks @zett42  

Its working